# Thai Characters not supported while converting html to pdf using itext XMLworker

Tags: java, itext, font-family

I am trying to convert HTML with Thai characters to pdf with "font-family: Arial Unicode MS, FreeSans;" but for some of the characters I am getting blank values in the pdf, Please suggest Any alternative for this or if I need to use any different font family which supports Thai characters.

Snippets of code that I am using

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, doc, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), fontImp);
```

Code I  used to register font provider

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
for(String path:fontPath){
     fontImp.register(path);}
```

> String which is supported: ช้อปปิ้งคลับ
>
> String which is not supported: นี (ประเทศไทย) จ

Comment: (1) Can you [edit] your question to provide some sample data containing Thai characters which are handled correctly - and some which are not (and mention which is which)? (2) Can you also show how you are creating the `FontProvider` (i.e. for `fontImp`)?

Comment: @andrewjames,  I have updated the code snippets with sample.

Comment: Thank you for the updates - unfortunately, I can recreate the issue, but I cannot solve it.

Comment: please share a sample HTML text and runnable stub to reproduce the issue

Comment: @shihabudheenk, Thanks, but it is resolved, I was using different font-face which was not supporting Thai langauge.

Comment: @Saurabhwagh which font-face or font-family you used which support Thai language??